# Couldn't be able to retrieve correct data from file due to \r in Python

Tags: python

Hello I am having trouble writing and then reading the exact data from the file.

What I am doing is first converting the `list` into `string` and then writing it to a file

```
S = [63, 16, 13, 30, 22, 13, 99, 68, 75, 91, 73, 80, 90]
```

Now If I do this to convert it into the Strings,

```
UpdatedPlainText = ''.join(chr(s) for s in S)

print("This is the Data:", UpdatedPlainText)
```

The data will be messed up due to the presence of two `int` values of `13` in original `List`, which is equals to `\r`

**Output:**

```
cDK[IPZ the Data: ?►
```

I know this is just displaying like this but the original data is still there.

The data can be retrieve back using this,
Here data is fist converted to integer before printed,

```
L = list(ord(s) for s in UpdatedPlainText)
print(L)
```

Output:

```
[63, 16, 13, 30, 22, 13, 99, 68, 75, 91, 73, 80, 90]
```

But instead of directly converting the data back to `integer` from `String`, 
If I first write the value of `UpdatedPlainText` in to a file,

```
PlainText = open('uText.txt', 'w')
PlainText.write(UpdatedPlainText)
PlainText.close()
```

and then `read` this file,

```
PlainText = open('uText.txt', 'r')
PlainText = PlainText.read()
```

and then print the data from the file,

```
L = list(ord(s) for s in PlainText)
print(L)
```

The output would be different,

```
[63, 16, 10, 30, 22, 10, 99, 68, 75, 91, 73, 80, 90]
```

As you can see, the value `13` is replaced with `10`, this is due to the `\r` which equals to `13`

How can I fix this problem ?
How can i prevent `13` from converting into `\r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On python documentation it says :

> Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written.

You are trying to retrieve data not like a text , so using binary mode is an option ( see answers above. The documentation goes on :

> This behind-the-scenes modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files.Be very careful to use binary mode when reading and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary files.

Like in your case, the default mode is altering the data.So if you want to use the read write option by default for some reason, you can try to encode the string before writing it to a file.

```
PlainText.encode('base64','strict')
```

And after reading, decode

```
PlainText.decode('base64','strict')
```

Too much work, but just another option.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening file in a "text" mode as opposed to "binary" more. As mentioned here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open you should use `'bw'` mode to avoid possible conversion of newline characters on write/read on some platforms.

```
PlainText = open('uText.txt', 'bw')
...
PlainText = open('uText.txt', 'br')
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file in binary mode:

```
with open('uText.txt', 'rb') as f:
    L = [x for x in f.read()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal just to store those numbers in a file and read them back later? Or are you specifically trying to learn/use binary? If your goal is to save the numbers, then you don't need to convert to a string, etc. Use json or something similar...

```
import json
with open('uText.txt','w') as txtfile:
    json.dump(S,txtfile)
```

To read them in later:

```
with open('uText.txt','r') as infile:
    newList = json.load(infile)
```